# White Box performance model for Hadoop

Tags: performance, hadoop, modeling

Hadoop Performance Models( http://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.0940.pdf) in this technical report they are using white box model for computing various cost. But i have following doubt in their work --

1. Are they still applicable for current Hadoop ?
2. I am not very clear how are they doing some formulation like CPU_cost in spill phase ( page 6 in the report).

Answer (score 0):

The [Starfish](http://www.cs.duke.edu/starfish/index.html) MapReduce tuning system is based on the performance model presented in the referenced report. Starfish and follow-up work is presented in a few papers that were published in top-class database / data management conferences:

- Herodotos Herodotou, Shivnath Babu: A What-if Engine for Cost-based MapReduce Optimization. IEEE Data Eng. Bull. 36(1): 5-14 (2013)
- Herodotos Herodotou, Shivnath Babu: Profiling, What-if Analysis, and Cost-based Optimization of MapReduce Programs. PVLDB 4(11): 1111-1122 (2011)
- Herodotos Herodotou, Fei Dong, Shivnath Babu: MapReduce Programming and Cost-based Optimization? Crossing this Chasm with Starfish. PVLDB 4(12): 1446-1449 (2011)
- Herodotos Herodotou, Harold Lim, Gang Luo, Nedyalko Borisov, Liang Dong, Fatma Bilgen Cetin, Shivnath Babu: Starfish: A Self-tuning System for Big Data Analytics. CIDR 2011: 261-272
- Harold Lim, Herodotos Herodotou, Shivnath Babu: Stubby: A Transformation-based Optimizer for MapReduce Workflows. CoRR abs/1208.0082 (2012)

I found a [repository](https://github.com/jwlent55/Starfish/tree/master/starfish) on Github which looks like it contains the Starfish code.

The papers and the code should contain more detail. Regarding the question whether the models are still applicable for the current Hadoop, I would assume that they still work. Maybe the authors of Starfish can help here.

Comment: I know all the above mentioned things. But after looking at all these stuff i am not getting enough details. And these guys are not responsive that is why, i am asking this.

Comment: Alright, that wasn't clear from the question. Would be nice if you could share the answers if you find them.